# How to add a hyperlink to a read-only field in EAMS

Tags: infor-eam

I have a field that displays as read-only in EAMS.   I would like to modify it using the screen designer (or other way) so that I can turn the field into a hyperlink of my choice.

For example the field now says:

ITEM27

I would like it to be set to:

http://server01/test.apx?item=ITEM27&wonum12345

But when you go to the screen designer, it only lets you use hyperlinks to URLs inside of EAM.  It is restricting it.   I would like to place a hyperlink to an external URL.  Does anyone know how to do this? (maybe there is some other way and not in the screen designer?)

Thanks Before Hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  As of 10.1.2, there is no way to do direct linking on fields.  It looks like they will have this feature in future versions.  The workaround now is to create a separate tab and define the custom url there.  There are still caveats since the page must be an https page if eam is running in https.  Here are the steps on how to accomplish it:

**Defining Custom Tabs for Screens**

Define custom tabs for existing screens. Specify an external URL to transfer values from the current screen. The URL information displays inside the tab in the Infor EAM system.

To define custom tabs for screens:

1. Open the Screens form. The system displays the List View page.
2. Select the screen for which to define custom tabs, and then click the Custom Tabs tab. The system displays the Custom Tabs page.
3. Click Insert Custom Tab. The system inserts a new Custom Tab Details record.
4. Enter a description for the new custom tab. The system automatically generates a Tab Code.
5. Type—Enter the custom tab type. 
   URL is the recommended setting because it is the only supported value.
6. Trusted Site—Select to allow access to the parent frame.
7. URL—Enter the URL for the custom tab.
8. Click Submit. The system saves the record and updates the Custom Tabs list.
9. Choose Administration-Security-User Groups to display the tab on a screen for the selected group.
10. Select the user group to give access to the custom tab.  Click the screen permissions tab.  Look for the new screen and give user group access to it.  Now the user group will have the custom tab available.

Note: The system automatically passes the key values from the header of the current form to the URL. This feature displays only information related to the selected record.

Comment: Are you using the Web Services Toolkit in C#?